# Google Sheets: every month on a specific date increase a cell number from a number in another cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Keeping track of finances!

Situation: every month I have a Direct Debit that moves an amount (e.g. £25.00) from one bank account to another to pay a bill.

Sheets: Every month on a specific date I want to automatically increase a specific cell that starts at £0.00 with the amount £25.00 that is in another cell.

Example:

- A1 - Netflix
- B1 - £25.00
- C1 - Netflix Payments
- D1 - £25.00 on Jan 1st, £50.00 on Feb 1st, £75.00 on Mar 1st etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In D1:

`=B1*(DATEDIF(DATEVALUE("Jan 1, 2022"),TODAY(),"m")+1)`

This will continue to multiply the value in B1 by the number of full months since the start date of January 1, 2022. That is, if the B1 value is 25, then today, the D1 value will be 25; on February 1, 2022, it will automatically read 50, on March 1 it will read 75, ad infinitum.

Answer (score 0):

Use now() formatted to month (as a number) and multiply the 25 by that result.

Jan is 1, Feb is 2, March is 3 etc

So 1 * 25 = 25, 2 * 25 = 50...

Comment: Could work, but it all needs to happen in the same cell. 
D1 would continue to increase £25 > £50 > £75, not in separate cells

Comment: @Chris where do I suggest you need multiple cells? Anyway as you have accepted the other answer I won't worry.